# In Symfony template (twig), how to fetch an object by its id?

Tags: symfony, twig

I have an ID of object in Symfony twig template. How can I transform this ID in the corresponding object? In EZ Publish there was a special FETCH function to do that, but in Symfony it does not exist. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Twig is for the view only, your data must be returned by the controller, where you can find object by it's ID

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that is what you need, but in twig you can do

```
{{ render(controller('YourBundle:Controller:Action', {'objectId' : objectId})) }}
```

to render some other object/content.